# Mocking private static method from a final class (utility class)

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, powermock

I am using Mockito and PowerMock to do some testing to my Java app. I was wondering how I can mock a private static method from a final class. I want to simulate an `Exception` when accessing one method but the only way I have found to do it is if the class can be instantiated and using the `spy()` method from PowerMock.

Could anyone help/guide me a little?

Comment: If you have control over the private static method in the final class, you may find it easier to refactor the method into an instance method in a non-final utility class. If your code is complex enough to need exception handling, it may be complex enough to be a free-standing mockable component all its own. (May not apply to you, but may apply to the next coder who reads this answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [example using PowerMock to mock public static methods](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic).

In case of a private method there must be some `public static` method somewhere to mock that calls this private method, as you can not call it directly. If you are only interested in an exception, you might throw the exception earlier (maybe - many assumptions)

Comment: I am not calling this method from a public static one, I am invoking it in a static block to execute it when the class is being loaded. Maybe I should change this behavior...

Comment: Ok, I do not see the full picture obviously. Maybe paste the full code snippet here, containing caller and callee.

Comment: I have changed the design of my app so I can do what you suggested in the first place. Thank you for the help!